# Fetch records which don't match the sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find out the records which are not matching the below query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `electric_transaction` LEFT JOIN `quarter_occupancy` ON 
`electric_transaction`.`Qtr_ID`=`quarter_occupancy`.`Qtr_ID` AND 
`electric_transaction`.`EmpNo`=`quarter_occupancy`.`EmpNo` WHERE `quarter_occupancy`.`Vacation 
 Date` IS NULL
```

The above query returns 3363 as output, whereas my actual count of rows in `electric_transaction` is 3365. That means two rows don't match the above condition. I want to find out those rows. How can I find out which rows they are?

Comment: Reverse the `WHERE`?

Comment: It returns `6` if I reverse the `WHERE`. It should be `2`

Comment: You use `COUNT(*)` which performs implicit GROUP BY which breaks the relation to source rows. Select primary keys columns/expressions for all mentioned tables instead and save into temptable. Then compare this list (with 3363 rows) and the rows which you predict to be selected (3365 rows), and find the difference between these lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `electric_transaction` LEFT JOIN `quarter_occupancy` ON 
`electric_transaction`.`Qtr_ID`=`quarter_occupancy`.`Qtr_ID` AND 
`electric_transaction`.`EmpNo`=`quarter_occupancy`.`EmpNo` WHERE `quarter_occupancy`.`Vacation 
 Date` IS NOT NULL
```

You have 2 rows that VacationDate is not null.

Comment: It returns `6` when I execute above query.

Comment: Try to Delete WHERE ? Is it returning 3365 or 3369?

Comment: Its returning 3369

Comment: So your query has 3369 rows, not 3365. In that case it means electric_transaction may be has 3365 rows but when you Left Joined it with quarter_occupancy it returns 3369 rows. You can check this out.